# Using array to count word and phrase matches in text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and trying to create a project for work. We hire transcriptionists based on a sample test file they listen to and type up. I've been trying to code a macro that will search the tests for specific keywords (some of which are used multiple times in the test), then give a message box with the results. This way we can gauge competency at a glance.

I've cadged together a prototype but there's one major problem: the counter doesn't seem to be counting right. I test it on a sample file that has all of the required keywords but it will only register about half of them. I'm not sure where the problem is and would appreciate any insight.

My code is below and a screenshot of the resulting message box is attached.

```
Sub WordCountTest()

    ' WordCountTest Macro

    'create definitions for search
    Dim wrd As range
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim searchlist()
    Dim numfound() As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim strResults As String

    'necessary search terms
    searchlist = Array("Deposition Subpoena", "Amend Notice of Deposition", _
                       "fellowed", "corneal", "refractive", "LASIK", _
                       "1989", "Cedars-Sinai", "Capital", _
                       "January 28 2016", "technicians'", _
                       "topography", "OCT", "sclera", _
                       "limbus sclerocorneal", "fundoscopy", _
                       "Indirect ophthalmoscope", "diopter", _
                       "Keratometry", "Tomey", _
                       "Cirrus OCT tomographer", _
                       "No, not on the front", "ablation")

    'searching text
    ReDim numfound(0 To UBound(searchlist))
    For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
        idx = 0
        For Each var In searchlist
            If Trim(wrd.Text) = searchlist(idx) Then
                numfound(idx) = numfound(idx) + 1
            End If
            idx = idx + 1
        Next var
    Next wrd

    idx = 0
    For Each var In searchlist
        strResults = strResults & searchlist(idx) & " : " & _
                     numfound(idx) & vbCr
        idx = idx + 1
    Next var

    MsgBox strResults

End Sub
```

---

[image: message box screenshot]

Comment: you're going to have a hard time matching up phrases since you're only looping on single words

Comment: It is an impressively clean chunk of code, though, if you're new to vba!

Comment: Although I've added some modifications I found much of the code online, so sadly I can't take credit for most of this. Thank you for pointing out that phrases were not being counted. I'm embarrassed I didn't pick up on that originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ArrFnd, strOut As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
ArrFnd = Array("Deposition Subpoena", "Amend Notice of Deposition", _
  "fellowed", "corneal", "refractive", "LASIK", "1989", "Cedars-Sinai", _
  "Capital", "January 28 2016", "technicians'", "topography", "OCT", _
  "limbus sclerocorneal", "fundoscopy", "Indirect ophthalmoscope", _
  "sclera", "diopter", "Keratometry", "Tomey", "Cirrus OCT tomographer", _
  "No, not on the front", "ablation")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  j = 0
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      j = j + 1
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
  k = k + j
  strOut = strOut & vbCr & ArrFnd(i) & ": " & j
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Results -" & strOut & vbCr & vbCr & "TOTAL: " & k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you could store document text in a string variable and split it in chuncks delimited by your keywords:

```
Sub WordCountTest()

    ' WordCountTest Macro

    'create definitions for search
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim searchlist()
    Dim numfound() As Long
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim strResults As String

    'necessary search terms
    searchlist = Array("Deposition Subpoena", "Amend Notice of Deposition", _
                       "fellowed", "corneal", "refractive", "LASIK", _
                       "1989", "Cedars-Sinai", "Capital", _
                       "January 28 2016", "technicians'", _
                       "topography", "OCT", "sclera", _
                       "limbus sclerocorneal", "fundoscopy", _
                       "Indirect ophthalmoscope", "diopter", _
                       "Keratometry", "Tomey", _
                       "Cirrus OCT tomographer", _
                       "No, not on the front", "ablation")


    Dim docTxt As String
    docTxt = ActiveDocument.Content.Text

    Dim arr() As String
    ReDim numfound(0 To UBound(searchlist))

    For Each var In searchlist
        arr = Split(docTxt, var) ' divide document text in chuncks delimited by current var occurrences
        numfound(idx) = UBound(arr)
        idx = idx + 1
    Next var

    idx = 0
    For Each var In searchlist
        strResults = strResults & searchlist(idx) & " : " & _
                     numfound(idx) & vbCr
        idx = idx + 1
    Next var

    MsgBox strResults

End Sub
```

yet you'll get "OCT" counted twice since found both in "OCT" and in "Cirrus OCT tomographer" (and the likes)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems working perfectly for words only. It will fail for counting phrases. Since I also consider the code as an impressively clean chunk of code as commented by Marcucciboy2, I tried to retain the main approach in the code already written. 
You may try to add the few lines

```
'At the beginning 
Dim wrd2 as range
Dim st,En as long 

'then at For Each var In searchlist
    For Each var In searchlist
            Set wrd2 = wrd
            If InStr(1, searchlist(idx), " ") > 0 Then
            st = wrd.Start
            En = st + Len(searchlist(idx))
            If En > ActiveDocument.Content.StoryLength Then En = ActiveDocument.Content.StoryLength
            Set wrd2 = ActiveDocument.Range(st, En)
            End If

            If Trim(wrd2.Text) = searchlist(idx) Then
                numfound(idx) = numfound(idx) + 1
            End If
            idx = idx + 1
        Next var
```

However, since it used to search a *"test file they listen to and type up”* think of the possibilities

1.The case of the words typed may not be exactly same of that in the search list.

2.Phrases may contain multiple spaces between words.

Comment: code isn't _"working perfectly"_, since it'd fail at finding matches between any document word (like "OCT") and any keyword (like "Cirrus OCT tomographer")

Comment: @DisplayName Thank you, I am editing my answer. I actually wanted to say it is working perfectly to “count specific words” as mentioned it the title and don’t want to change the clean approach taken by someone who is new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the native `Find` function in Word to search for each word (`Find.Execute` across the entire range until you find no more). This works quite quickly (especially if you turn screen updating off) and you have the other options such as ignore case and use word roots/extensions or wildcards.

I have used this method in conjuction with RegEx formula in the wildcard search to identify acronyms and defined terms.